# Add additional test tasks in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

In rails 4.x you used to be able to easily add additional `Rails::TestTask`s that would run alongside the core Rails app tests during `rake test`. For instance, like this:

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2014/04/26/adding-directory-to-rake-test.html

In Rails 5, none of the approaches I've seen seem to work, and while it seems to be documented/understood around the internet that they no longer work, I haven't seen any mention of the new way to do things.

Anybody know?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing; did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( Tried a bunch of different ways with no success.

Answer (score 2):

It still works but changed in Rails 5.1.3.
Basically rails test runner now picks up everything matching `test/**/*_test.rb` except files matching `test/system/**/*_test.rb` so you may not have to do anything if your tests are already within test folder.

You can still setup specific test task under `test/` like this:

```
namespace :test do
  %w[queries reporters services workers].each do |name|
    task name => 'test:prepare' do
      $LOAD_PATH << 'test'
      Rails::TestUnit::Runner.rake_run(["test/#{name}"])
    end
  end
end
```